ошибка подключения к БД MySQL Tls
Создал игру с подключением к БД, на localhost все идеально работало. Как только перенес на хостинг начали возникать проблемы. Ошибка возникает в этих строчках
string connStr = "server=ip;uid=myuid;database=database;pwd=mypass;";
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connStr)

Сама ошибка:
TlsException: Handshake failed - error code: UNITYTLS_INTERNAL_ERROR, verify result: UNITYTLS_X509VERIFY_NOT_DONE
Mono.Unity.Debug.CheckAndThrow (Mono.Unity.UnityTls+unitytls_errorstate errorState, Mono.Unity.UnityTls+unitytls_x509verify_result verifyResult, System.String context, Mono.Security.Interface.AlertDescription defaultAlert) (at <baff8c0412fc498b96434aff94e19558>:0)
Mono.Unity.UnityTlsContext.ProcessHandshake () (at <baff8c0412fc498b96434aff94e19558>:0)
Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status, System.Boolean renegotiate) (at <baff8c0412fc498b96434aff94e19558>:0)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake(Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus,bool)
Mono.Net.Security.AsyncHandshakeRequest.Run (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) (at <baff8c0412fc498b96434aff94e19558>:0)
Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.ProcessOperation (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) (at <baff8c0412fc498b96434aff94e19558>:0)
Rethrow as AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) (at <baff8c0412fc498b96434aff94e19558>:0)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.AuthenticateAsClient(string,System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection,System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols,bool)
System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) (at <baff8c0412fc498b96434aff94e19558>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.StartSSL () (at <7bbc3a3bbac54b1f9f89b5c26f19ea96>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open () (at <7bbc3a3bbac54b1f9f89b5c26f19ea96>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open () (at <7bbc3a3bbac54b1f9f89b5c26f19ea96>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) (at <7bbc3a3bbac54b1f9f89b5c26f19ea96>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection () (at <7bbc3a3bbac54b1f9f89b5c26f19ea96>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection () (at <7bbc3a3bbac54b1f9f89b5c26f19ea96>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver () (at <7bbc3a3bbac54b1f9f89b5c26f19ea96>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection () (at <7bbc3a3bbac54b1f9f89b5c26f19ea96>:0)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open () (at <7bbc3a3bbac54b1f9f89b5c26f19ea96>:0)
DataBaseHandler.Select (System.String query) (at Assets/Scripts/Classes/DataBase_Handler.cs:19)
DataBaseHandler.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Classes/DataBase_Handler.cs:52)

На самом же сервере если смотреть логи MySQL я вижу такую строчку
2024-05-06T14:57:08.693087Z 8 [Warning] [MY-010055] [Server] IP address 'мой айпи' could not be resolved: Name or service not known


MySQL достаточно вменяемо пишет, что не может отресолвить IP в имя хоста. Если подключаетесь по адресу - включите skip_name_resolve. Или используйте распознаваемое имя вместо IP.

@Akina, спасибо большое за возможное решение. Но тем не менее это не сильно помогло, либо я что-то сделал не так. Как я понял, чтобы включить skip_name_resolve я добавил в файл конфигурации MySQL 2 строки
[mysqld] skip_name_resolve
Что не очень помогло. Уже после, я отменил изменения и использовал распознаваемое имя хоста. Что вызвало такую же ошибку
TlsException: Handshake failed - error code: UNITYTLS_INTERNAL_ERROR, verify result: UNITYTLS_X509VERIFY_NOT_DONE

Как я понял, чтобы включить skip_name_resolve я добавил в файл конфигурации MySQL 2 строки [mysqld] skip_name_resolve Ну что вы все сразу бросаетесь конфиг править? Сперва попробуйте опцией командной строки запуска сервиса - так оно проще. Что вызвало такую же ошибку Это не ошибка. Это то, как её понял коннектор. Саму ошибку надо смотреть в Error Log на стороне MySQL. И соответственно там же в мануале (плюс в мануале на коннектор) читать, как её исправлять.
